# what is the right way to delete all features from featureLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I have a `featureLayer` and I don't want to kill it and create another one. I want to delete all features from the current featureLayer. I found that I can use `applyEdits` method but in order to use it I need to have all features I want to delete. Whilst I don't want to store them separately. Do you know a better way to empty my featureLayer when using the ArcGIS Javascript API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use featureLayer.selectFeatures() with, as Kirk suggested, a where clause that will return all your features. Once you have all your features, pass them to applyEdits() as the deletes.

Comment: Won't this return a lot of features to the client?  If this is a large dataset it could really be slow.

Comment: The only problem is I can't specify the right where clause - I tried "1 = 1", "OBJECTID > 0", etc. But every time I have an error "FeatureLayer::selectFeatures - query contains one or more unsupported parameters". The code  var query = new esri.tasks.Query(); query.where = "1 = 1"; featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, ...);

Comment: Perhaps, if featurelayer is not connected with any feature service, it doen't support where clauses. What do you think?

Comment: "if featurelayer is not connected with any feature service, it doen't support where clauses" - that's correct, but if so it also wouldn't support editing. From the API reference: "If the underlying layer ... is from a Feature Service, its features can be edited", implying that your featureLayer IS connected to a feature service

Comment: "it also wouldn't support editing" - I support editing even if it is not connected with service. Hovewer, I had to make some workarounds.

Answer (score 4):

Try making a [REST delete features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/fsdelete.html) call with a where clause "1 = 1" or something similar.

Comment: hi is there any syntax to the REST delete features call? could you provide me an example as I am attempting to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the feature layer on the client side (no server side url), then you cannot use a query with a where clause. I was able to work around this by searching the extent of the map and then deleting all the items that I found. For example:

```
function removeAllLayerFeatures(map, layer) {
    require(['esri/tasks/query', 'esri/layers/FeatureLayer'], function (Query, FeatureLayer) {
        var query = new Query();
        query.geometry = map.extent;
        layer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (results) {
            for (var key in results) {
                layer.remove(results[key]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [clear()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#clear) method:

> Clears all graphics.

```
featureLayer.clear();
```

Answer (score -2):

Use an [Update Cursor](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/bdb9558a-d78d-446c-a9d8-f35f9eb44a5b.htm#Update_Cursors), selecting all features ("*").

Use *IFeature.Delete()*, and store when done.

Comment: This question is asking for a JavaScript solution, not ArcObjects.

Comment: Oops...my mistake! Please ignore.